# Inserting value stored in a pipeline variable as a new row of sink dataset data

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb, union, pipeline

In ADF, I generate pipeline variables such as the pipeline run time, rows copied count, copy status etc. from various activities. I then use Set Variable to create a JSON string consisting of the above values. Now I want to store this string into an existing CosmosDB as a new record.

I cannot use Azure Functions or a Notebook job to insert, as I want it to be possible within ADF without additional dependencies.

I have tried using Data Flow, but it is unable to add a new record from values in a pipeline variable. I cannot use a separate data source to union and add into the CosmosDB as the values I want inserted are generated during runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the individual pipeline variables like `pipeline run time` , `copied rows count`, `copy status` as they are (without creating a json document consisting of all values) and use the copy activity in adf to insert the values in cosmos db container. Below is the approach.

- Three pipeline variables `pipeline run time` , `copied rows count`, `copy status`  are taken and their values are set using set variable activity here.

[image]

- Then a copy activity is taken with a dummy source dataset. Source dataset has one row. In source tab of copy activity, New columns are added by clicking `+New` in additional columns. All three columns are set with the value that is defined using set variable activity.

[image]

- Then sink dataset is taken for cosmos dB
  with `insert` as write behavior.

[image]

- Then in Mapping section, Schema is imported by giving sample values for the pipeline variables. Then all additional columns that is created in source are mapped to sink columns.

[image]

- When pipeline is run, data is inserted to cosmos dB.

Comment: Thanks Aswin, this is a working solution!

It does have the limitation of having to rely on a empty file with one empty row but it does the job. It also does not work with the same CosmosDB container with `SELECT TOP 0 * FROM c` or similar query as the source. It also must have all expected output columns mapped as otherwise those columns would not be output even with blank values.

Comment: Yes. It needs an empty file.

Comment: Are there any alternative solutions that do not use an empty file? This solution works fine but does add that additional dependency.

Comment: You can try this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-document). In ADF, try using web activity and give the corresponding URL and post method. In body, give the variable which has Json data in body.